# How to calculate gps accuracy in meters from nmea sentence information

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, nmea

I have android app that gets GPGGA and GPRMC sentences form bluetooth gps receiver, how to calculate horizontal accuracy of given position with in meters?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also interested in this

Comment: not really, i just assumed that HDOP is accuracy in meters (0.7 m - 0.9 m) looks nice to user :D

Comment: HDOP is NOT an accuracy in meters.HDOP*(4 or 5) gives a rough estimate of meters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you provide the HDOP as an accuracy in meters as you stated in your comments, you are providing a completely false fantasy value.

As an alternative answer that is related to the actual question, I just wanted to provide a relevant link to the GIS Stackexchange site where this question has also been asked: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97774/how-can-i-convert-horizontal-dilution-of-position-to-a-radius-of-68-confidence

In short: it is not trivial, and the HDOP alone is not sufficient for a reliable accuracy. As user30184 commented, some simply use e.g. 3-5 m as the accuracy of the device and then multiply it with HDOP to get an accuracy.

But in general, let me quote claudegps from [this also provided link](https://www.gps-forums.com/threads/roughtly-converting-dop-to-metric-error.40105/#post-206331):

> You can't. DOP is not an indicator of "error" or "accuracy". Bad DOP
>   does not always mean bad accuracy for example. Moreover the "accuracy"
>   should not consider only DOP: Imagine to be indoor (very low signal, a
>   lot of multipath ecc) but with a good DOP: you may have a very bad
>   accuracy even with a good DOP... So your indication DOP-based will be
>   wrong. Unfortunately, if you have only NMEA sentences, you usually
>   don't have enough data to estimate the accuracy (that can be done
>   internally to the receiver as it have much more informations inside).

You may also have a look at this link: https://www.gps-forums.com/threads/estimating-accuracy-from-raw-nmea-data.46273/ And last but not least, from [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141214015213/http://www.montana.edu/gps/slides/2GPSAccuracy.pdf):

> 6 sources of error (and additional  factors) affect the accuracy of GPS positions

Answer (score 2):

may this can help:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/how-correct-is-the-accuracy-value-given-by-gps-devices

and based on http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm
GPGGA contain Horizontal Dilution of Precision (HDOP)
and more sattelite locked you will get better accuracy

Comment: all problem is that i get different accuracy from 
Bluetooth GPS (by GG MobLab) and actual nmea GPGGA sentence. So i think do i need to calculate something more or not?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and neither do the links

Comment: As i understood, answer meant that HDOP stands for horizontal acuracy in meters so my case is solved i guess.